# Firebase - App that sends realtime data (location) between Users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating an Android application which requires realtime data exchange of location.

I will have an application, lets call it AppA. I want to send the Latitude and Longitude location of User A to another User B. I want to send realtime data from one instance of an app to another.

Can I use FCM for exchanging data messages or should I update it in the Firebase database and then retrieve it?

Comment: Take a look here : https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java

Comment: @RamithDR Its good but data  (shops in the example) is preloaded to database, i want realtime updates.

Comment: Then I believe the Firebase database would suite your needs, it is infact a realtime database and you can connect several apps to one database too.

Comment: i need an approach. Like steps or flow!

Comment: Why don't you start by explaining more on your app and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @RamithDR The app is similar to OLA,UBER or generally related to Carpooling! I need the realtime location of the driver  in client apps.

Comment: @jay: were you able to get this running? If so how?

Comment: @Zax i was storing the data in fire base from one side and fetching it from another side.

Answer (score 0):

A basic clue to do this is, Angular2 and Firebase Mix!

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/location');
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  displayLocation(snapshot.val());
});
```

In the above code, the `value` will help you in accessing the data realtime. So, to update this in your app in realtime, you can use Angular2 on your View.

In the back-end part, you can assign public variables for the latitude and longitude, and use it directly in to the View.

Reference:

[Firebase Retrieval Realtime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data)

[Angular2 Docs](https://angular.io/)

This can help!